# Multiple journeys on same route - roundtrip tickets in bulk (plane)

Tags: air-travel, tickets, routes

I've traveled one and the same route multiple times now, like every week.
No I'm wondering if there is a possibility of buying a ticket which will allow me to travel this special route every week by just buying a single ticket.

For example my idea is of specifying particular flights: Monday 09.00 out and Friday 17.00 in for for each week for the whole year. But in best case it should also be possible to not check in for some weeks/flights.

Once I lived in Switzerland I had such a route-based ticked for train service.

Does anybody know about any airline that offers such tickets?

Comment: Presumably you cannot choose any random airline so maybe it would make more sense to specify the route or at least the countries/regions involved in the question.

Comment: currently I'm traveling between Zurich and Berlin.  Even if somebody has experience with any other airline that is offering such a service, I'd be interested in knowing about it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is one airline that sells roundtrip tickets in bulk, Aeroflot. You can only purchase a bulk ticket between Moscow and other Russian cities. First roundtrip leg will be with a fixed dates, subsequent are open dated. You can buy 4-16 roundtrips, with some discount for bulk purchase. Here is their web page with more details (in Russian only):

http://www.aeroflot.ru/cms/special_offers/business_travel

Just found a similar American Airlines program:

http://www.aairpass.com

So it really depends on the individual carrier

Answer (score 1):

Answering questions like this in the negative is very hard because you need to provide sources that something doesn't exist :) but indeed such tickets do not exist. Swiss, Lufthansa and Air Berlin flies this city pair but that's almost irrelevant as no airlines offer such.